# Upload File to the Dropbox public folder using the iphoneSDK

Tags: iphone, ios, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am currently developing an application which uploads files to the App Folder in the Dropbox Account of the user. I am using the iOS SDK of Dropbox version 1.1. The problem I am facing is that I want to get the link of the files just uploaded so that I can share them with others.

For that, I came to know that the uploaded files should be inside the Public directory in my Dropbox account. I came across this following link

[Get Public Link of Dropbox Files](http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=34252)

I wanted to know how can I move the files from inside the /Apps/MyAppName/File location to the Public location. I have come across the following method in the API -

```
- (void)moveFrom:(NSString*)from_path toPath:(NSString *)to_path;
```

This method is located in the file DBRestClient.h in the SDK. What should the value which needs to be passed on as parameters to this function be? I apologize beforehand if you find my question to be trivial, but I really wanted to know the solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used this to share a file in my app folder and that works fine

paste these code to make a file sharable

```
  [[self restClient] loadSharableLinkForFile:filePath];
```

paste these code to get the link of the shared file

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)restClient loadedSharableLink:(NSString*)link 
           forFile:(NSString*)path{
    NSLog(@"link %@",link); //this is the sharable link 
    NSLog(@"File Path %@ ",path); // this is the path of the file 

}

- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)restClient loadSharableLinkFailedWithError:(NSError*)error{
    NSLog(@"Error %@",error);
}
```

Comment: you helped me too ., thank you ., i saw your post in DropBox forum http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=56941#post-416051 and got some help from their reply ., that helps me., anyway Happy Coding

Comment: and you should know that these sharable links will expire with some time interval